# Solspace Super Serach Matrix Date Range

Tags: matrix, low-search, supersearch

I need to implement the following search on my ee site

I have a matrix field with the following columns

```
start date
end date
```

For example, I have an entry with 2 rows in my matrix column where the values listed are dates that are not available

Entry Title: Entry 1
Matrix values
Start Date   -  End Date
01/01/2014 - 15/01/2014
01/02/2014 - 20/02/2014

On my search form I have a search form with start date and end date

The user searches with the the following details
**Start Date   -  End Date

02/01/2014 - 10/01/2014**
When the users searches no results are displayed as the dates the user selected are in the matrix field as not available

The user searches with the the following details
**Start Date   -  End Date

16/01/2014 - 20/01/2014**
Entry 1 is returned as the dates selected are not in the unavailable list for that entry

**Is this possible with low search and is there an example?**
Thanks

Comment: I have already answered this here: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/matrix_date_search#reply_14197657

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Matrix data columns need to be set to "searchable" for its data to be stored, **as a concatenated string**, in `exp_channel_data`. Once that is set up, searching in this Matrix field using Super Search is limited since Super Search will only look for a string match between your search and what is stored in `exp_channel_data`. In other words, there are no date-based calculations being made. Further, for date columns, it might be possible that this data is saved as a unix timestamp, so you would have to make your search match an exact unix timestamp stored in `exp_channel_data`.

Comment: Hi

Thanks

I have a custom import for my data and I an importing the the matrix data into table exp_matrix_data

So if I have the matrix columns set as searchable will the entry in exp_channel_data be automatically created/entered?

Or is there a way to manage this?

Comment: For your searchable data to end up in exp_channel_data, you will need to re-save every entry using your Matrix custom field. Matrix saves to exp_channel_data on entry save.

Comment: Thanks If I used your imported extension would I have still re-save every entry that was imported?

Comment: Yes. By the way, the above answer is really saying that searching for dates within a Matrix field isn't really easily possible. Super Search doesn't see the data as "date" data in exp_channel_data.